# How to determine if all objects inside List<T> has the same property value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I believe its not a hard one, but could not found anything.
I have a `List` of objects and i would like to write a query to determine if a specific property of **all** the objects has the value of 1 or not.
I would like to do that using `LINQ` \ `Lambda`.

```
    private bool IsTheSame(List<ContenderLeague> TryUpgradeConts)
    {
        bool IsTheSameValue = true;
        foreach (ContenderLeague c in TryUpgradeConts)
        {
            if (c.Contender.Factor != 1)
            {
                IsTheSameValue = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return IsTheSameValue;
    }
```

Comment: [All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Linq All ie `IsTheSameValue = TryUpgradeConts.All(c => c.Contender.Factor == 1)`

Comment: The code you provided doesnt check whether the condition is met for all Elements. It only tells you if there are Any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you describe is using `All` extension method as you can see in the other answers:

```
return TryUpgradeConts.All(c=>c.Contender.Factor == 1);
```

But the real translation of your code is using `Any`:

```
return TryUpgradeConts.Any(c=>c.Contender.Factor != 1);
```

You are trying to find some element which doesn't meet the condition

Answer (score 8):

```
using System.Linq; // at the top of your code file
```

*Altered code*

```
var allHaveContederFactorValueOne = TryUpgradeConts.All(i => i.Contender.Factor == 1);
```

Learn how to use lambdas expressions and the various built in functions in the framework like `All`, `Any`, `Where`, etc. They make coding much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Use the linq `.All()` method.  Something like below should work.

```
private bool IsTheSame(List<ContenderLeague> TryUpgradeConts)
{
    return TryUpgradeConts.All(c => c.Contender.Factor == 1);
}
```